# Kendo Treeview with local datasource issue:TypeError: i is undefined

Tags: kendo-ui, treeview, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-treeview

I bind the datasource and select/change event in the treeview,When I　click the treeview node,it is wrong?How to deal with it?[image],My code is here:

```
  <div id="TreeView"></div>
      var dataSource = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
                data: [{ text: "text1"  },
                    {  text: "text2" }
                ]
            });
            $("#TreeView").kendoTreeView({
                autoBind: false,
                dataSource: dataSource,
                select: function (e) {
                    if (this.text(e.node).indexOf('text1') != -1) {
                      alert("text1");
                    }
                }
            });
            dataSource.read();
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem. I've copier your code on this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/gTfq8/ (no change). Can you check if it fails?

Comment: @flower are you certain you are including the correct jquery version, the same version that comes with the telerik package?